# Find the "concise mathematical definition" of a function in SICP

Tags: math, scheme, sicp

*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* gives this implementation of Ackermann's function:

```
(define (A x y) 
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
      ((= x 0) (* 2 y))
      ((= y 1) 2)
      (else (A (- x 1) (A x (- y 1))))))
```

Exercise 1.10 asks for the "concise mathematical definitions" of the following functions that call `A`:

```
(define (f n) (A 0 n)) 
(define (g n) (A 1 n)) 
(define (h n) (A 2 n))
```

The outputs of `f` and `g` for integers 1 - 4 are recognizable as 2n and 2^n. But `h` is `2^(2^n-1)`, a formula I could not recognize just by looking for a pattern in the outputs. How is one meant to complete this exercise? Is there a method for deriving the mathematical notation, perhaps based on the notation for Ackermann's function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book has already introduced the substitution method, so it's not wrong to use that.

Start with `(A 0 n)`

This is

```
(cond ((= n 0) 0)
      ((= 0 0) (* 2 n))
      ((= 0 1) 2)
      (else (A (- 0 1) (A 0 (- n 1)))))
```

which is clearly 2n.

Next, `(A 1 n)` is

```
(cond ((= n 0) 0)
      ((= 1 0) (* 2 n))
      ((= n 1) 2)
      (else (A (- 1 1) (A 1 (- n 1))))))
```

which is

```
(A 0 (A 1 (- n 1)))
```

or, taking advantage of the previous step,

```
(* 2 (A 1 (- n 1))
```

That is,

```
A 1 n = 2 * (A 1 (n-1))
      = 2 * 2 * (A 1 (n-2))
      = ...
```

Since we know that `A x 1 = 2` for all `x`, we see that

```
A 1 n = 2 * 2 * ... * 2
```

with `n` factors, i.e. 2<sup>n</sup>.

Applying similar reasoning to the last case left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for. Is there a "concise" mathematical definition for this?

Answer (score 2):

Having already figured out that (f n) = (* 2 n) and (g n) = (expt 2 n) we can use that information along with the definition of A to figure out what (A 2 n) will be:

Putting in x=2:

```
(define (A2 y) 
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (A 1 (A2 (- y 1))))))
```

Putting in the fact (A 1 n) = (expt 2 n)

```
(define (A2 y) 
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (expt 2 (A2 (- y 1))))))
```

from this you can see the recursion pattern more clearly that A2 gives nested powers of two like 2^(2^(2^2)). I think your answer 2^(2^n-1) may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scheme itself to help find answers to this:

```
(define (*^ x y) `(* ,x ,y))

(define (A x y)
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= x 0) (*^ 2 y))
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (A (- x 1) (A x (- y 1))))))

;> (A 0 100)
;'(* 2 100)
;> (A 0 234)
;'(* 2 234)
```

suggests (A 0 n) = (* 2 n).

---

```
(define (*^ x y) `(* ,x ,y))

(define (A x y)
  (cond ((= x 0) (*^ 2 y))
        ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (A (- x 1) (A x (- y 1))))))

;> (A 1 10)
;'(* 2 (* 2 (* 2 (* 2 (* 2 (* 2 (* 2 (* 2 (* 2 2)))))))))
;> (A 1 5)
;'(* 2 (* 2 (* 2 (* 2 2))))
```

reordered the rules to avoid an error. we can see its doing *2 n times, so 2^n.

---

```
(define (*^ x y) `(* ,x ,y))

(define (A x y)
  (cond ((= x 0) (*^ 2 y))
        ((= x 1) `(expt 2 ,y))
        ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (A (- x 1) (A x (- y 1))))))

;> (A 2 5)
;'(expt 2 (expt 2 (expt 2 (expt 2 2))))
;> (A 2 6)
;'(expt 2 (expt 2 (expt 2 (expt 2 (expt 2 2)))))
```

This confirms the idea that we get a tower of exponents.